# How can I simulate this paragraph about changing the learning rate picked from Resnet paper?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

While going through this paper, I found they are changing learning rate in between of training/validation iterations.

> We start with a learning rate of 0.1, divide it by 10 at 32k and 48k iterations, and terminate training at 64k iterations, which is determined on a 45k/5k train/val split.

[image]

Comment: Which error? Can you be more specific?

Comment: training error. they say that "they used learning rate 0.01 util the training error is below 80%" and they don't mention about how the found the error. I guess by error they are specifying the top1% accuracy.

Comment: Can you provide the paper where you found that quote?

Comment: @abhi your question was too broad, if you had provided the source or image, community would be glad to answer your questions because your question make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, You're probably looking for
[torch.optim.lr_scheduler](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#how-to-adjust-learning-rate)

Specifically, You can implement the reduction of *learning_rate* after *n* epochs using [lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR.html#torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR)

Following the advised way to use lr_schedulers, You will need to recalculate the milestones from *steps* to *epochs* as the updates are done after the whole epochs rather than steps.

If that won't give You the satisfactory result, You can actually "cheat" by calling
`scheduler.step()` after each batch (step) and then passing the milestones in number of steps.
Remember then not to confuse yourself or the ones that will happen to edit Your code some day, at least put a comment to indicate that You're using the library function in a little less obvious way :D